# Regular Expressions with conditions

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
this is a string [[and]] it is [[awesome|amazing]]
```

I have the following regular expression so far:

```
(?<mygroup>(?<=\[\[).+?(?=\]\]))
```

I am basically trying to capture everything inside the brackets. However, I need to add another condition that says: If the matched result contains a pipe delimiter then only return the word to the right of the pipe delimiter. If there is no pipe then just return everything inside the brackets.

The parsing result I am looking for given the example above should look like:

and
amazing

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 RegExp question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443149/as3-regexp-question)

Comment: Would   (.*|)?(.*)  do the trick? First group is either stuff up to the pipe, or nothing. Second group is what you're looking for...

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<mygroup>(?<=\[\[)([^|\]]*|)?([^|]+?)(?=\]\]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
(?<=\[\[[^\]]*?)(?!\w+\|)\w+(?=\]\])
```

it matches both `and` and `amazing` words in your test example. You could check it out, I created a test app on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/KHqZn).

Answer (score 0):

From the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) info page:

> The tremendous power and expressivity
>   of modern regular expressions can
>   seduce the gullible — or the foolhardy
>   — into trying to use regexes on every
>   string‐related task they come across.

My advice: Just grab what is between the brackets and parse it after.

Regular expressions are not the answer to everything. May those who follow after you be spared from deciphering the regex you come up with.